# What is the average and worst-case time complexity of my string searching algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o

I created this algorithm to return the index of the first occurrence of a needle in a haystack, or -1 if the needle is not part of the haystack. It passed on LeetCode with a lower-bound of one and an upper-bound of ten to the power of four for both needle and haystack and people were saying that O(n * m) solutions weren't passing at all, so I assume the average time complexity is somewhat better than that; however, I can't tell for sure as the main while loop's time complexity is tough to understand.

The code is:

```
def stringSearch(haystack, needle):
    s = []
    
    if len(needle) == 1:
        for i,n in enumerate(haystack):
            if n == needle:
                return i
        return -1

    for i,n in enumerate(haystack):
        if n == needle[0] and (len(haystack) - i) >= len(needle):
            s.append(i)
    
    new = []
    for i in s:
        if i + 1 < len(haystack) and haystack[i + 1] == needle[1]:
            new.append((i, i + 1, 2))
    if new and len(needle) == 2:
        return new[0][0]

    while 1:
        temp = []
        for first, start, check in new:
            if haystack[start + 1] == needle[check]:
                temp.append((first, start + 1, check + 1))
                if check + 1 >= len(needle):
                    return first
        if not temp:
            return -1
        new = temp
stringSearch("", "")
```

The worst-case is evidently cases where haystack is a giant repeating pattern, and needle follows that pattern in such cases as "hahahahahahahah" and "haha" or "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" and "aa".

Comment: @rioV8 Hey Rio, thanks for your concern regarding my learning. To answer your question, I don't ask the time or space complexity for all of my code, nor plan to, as I typically know it. But in very special cases, I ask online for help because I don't know it, and rather than sift through an 800-page programming book, I hope to get a understandable answer in a timely fashion!

Comment: `O(n*m)` is definitely enough for n, m bounded by 10^4. A simple `return haystack.find(needle)` should suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm essentially performs a breadth-first search, where you extend all partial matches you found in a previous iteration by one character and keep those that still match. So for a worst case scenario we would want to have as many partial matches as possible for as many iterations as possible.

One such worst case input could be a haystack with an even size, with  times the letter "a", and a needle with =/2 characters that are all "a", except the last letter, which would be a "b". So for instance, if  is 10:

```
haystack = "aaaaaaaaaa"
needle   = "aaaab"
```

The `while 1:` loop will make /2−2 iterations (the "minus-2" is the consequence of already having matches with 2 letters before that loop starts).

The inner `for first, start, check in new` loop will make /2+1 iterations

Taking that together, the inner `if` statement will be executed (/2-2)(/2+1) times, i.e. ²/4−/2−2 times, which is O(²), and is therefore the time complexity of your algorithm.

> people were saying that O(n * m) solutions weren't passing at all

You have given proof that their claim is false. Here it is important to realise that time complexity says absolutely *nothing* about how much time an algorithm will need to process *actual* (finite!) inputs. Time complexity is about *asymptotic* behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for fixing that typo, @Unmitigated!